# How to prompt username and application directory with AppleScript?

Tags: templates, ms-word, network-programming, applescript

I have a bunch of Word and Powerpoint templates that I want to copy and possibly overwrite from a company network location to the `/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/` etc. location where templates are stored. It would be nice if I hadn't have to prompt the user for username to get the `/Users/[username]/Library` part of the local template path.

Can someone please help me as to what to do? I have never tried AppleScript before though I'm familiar with VBScript, JavaScript and such a bit, but this AppleScript is really weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the input has some kind of identifier there will always have to be user interaction to correctly find the destination location in a dynamic script like this. You can set up a prompt that only asks for a username and not a whole path would be my suggestion base on what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, hope you can follow this code.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set homePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
    set thePath to homePath & "Library/Application Support/App Store/"
    set desktopPath to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder)
    do shell script "cp -r " & quoted form of thePath & " " & quoted form of desktopPath
end tell
```

What this does is to get the path to `user/Library/Application Support/App Store/` and copying all its files to your desktop.

It executes the unix command `cp -r` to copy the folders content. [Wiki cp command page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_%28Unix%29)

POSIX path command is required because applescript and unix does not use the same path syntax, and 'quoted form of' is needed because otherwise the command will not work properly because of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this looking for an answer to another issue but I noticed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24381036/1952287) was somewhat long and not really necessary.  It might be due to the age of the question but now in AppleScript you can target an user's Application Support directory with a built in one liner of:

```
path to application support from user domain
```

the user's library would be with:

```
path to library folder from user domain
```

The two above are for `alias path` but if you want `path/to/whatever/` you can use `Posix path` such as:

```
set foo to POSIX path of (path to application support from user domain)
set bar to POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain)
```